# How to change the names from table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called user. And it contains names like

```
     user
   xyz.abc
   123.abc
   atr.abc
   etc.....
```

I need a query such that output should not contain the names after dot(.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '.', 1) from USER;
```

Comment: I have two tables:  workstation and dept ,containing some similar columns in both the tables. Here i want to select unique names from workstation which are not in dept..                                  I need ur help its urgent can u help me

Comment: Hi @Raj, please create new question. I think you will get more feedback for your problem by create new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select rtrim(username,'.') from user
```